# which is a good place to define plans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, hash

I have a rails application, which has 3-4 plans and each plan has 3 attributes. A user can subscribe to any one of the plans. Have tried two options:

```
1. Having plans table in the application. 
2. Having hash value in environment.rb file.
```

what's a good place to define plans??

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to create seeds, in the `db/seeds.rb` file.
You can see this [old screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/179-seed-data) to get the idea, which basically haven't changed in newer Rails versions.

For a more updated reference you can check this: http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/seed_rb.html

Answer (score 0):

If your app's plan is no longer increase, then put the hash value in environment.rb is fine.But if the plans will increase in the future, you may want to put the plans in database.Hope it would help.